# Meta tags issue with Python Scrapy. KeyError for selected fields

Tags: python, scrapy

Complete newbie here and in the process of learning web scraping with scrapy. So please excuse any thing that might sound "stupid" from me.

A very simple setup here to extract some data from a real estate portal:

```
class RightmoveSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rightmove'
    allowed_domains = ['rightmove.co.uk']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/api/_search?locationIdentifier=POSTCODE%5E620536&numberOfPropertiesPerPage=24&radius=1.0&sortType=2&viewType=LIST&channel=BUY&currencyCode=GBP&index=25'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        json_parse = json.loads(response.text)
        # Find number of properties on page
        property_count = len(json_parse["properties"])

        # Loop through each property and collect some data
        for i in range(property_count):
            title = json_parse["properties"][i]["propertyTypeFullDescription"]
            address = json_parse["properties"][i]["displayAddress"]
            prop_type = json_parse["properties"][i]["propertySubType"]
            price = json_parse["properties"][i]["price"]["amount"]
            seller = json_parse["properties"][i]["customer"]["brandTradingName"]

            # Return Image URLs as list because that is the desired format
            image_urls = []
            img_count = len(json_parse["properties"][i]["propertyImages"]["images"])
            for a in range(img_count):
                image = json_parse["properties"][i]["propertyImages"]["images"][a]["url"]
                image = "https://media.rightmove.co.uk/" + image
                image_urls.append(image)

            property_url = "https://www.rightmove.co.uk" + json_parse["properties"][i]["propertyUrl"]

            # Creating a meta dict from the above data to be added to the Request
            meta_dict = {
                "title": title,
                "address": address,
                "prop_type": prop_type,
                "price": price,
                "seller": seller,
                "image_urls": image_urls
            }

            yield Request(url=property_url, meta=meta_dict, callback=self.parse_item)

        # Go through pagination to get all Request. UNCOMMENT AFTER TESTING
        # current_index = int(response.url.rsplit("=")[-1])
        # total_count = int(json_parse["resultCount"])
        # if current_index+25 < total_count:
        #     next_url = f"https://www.rightmove.co.uk/api/_search?locationIdentifier=POSTCODE%5E620536&numberOfPropertiesPerPage=24&radius=1.0&sortType=2&viewType=LIST&channel=BUY&currencyCode=GBP&index={current_index+25}"
        #     yield Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # using print for testing respose.meta
        # print(response.meta)

        l = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesDataItem(), response=response)
        l.add_value("title", response.meta["title"])
        l.add_value("address", response.meta["address"])
        l.add_value("prop_type", response.meta["prop_type"])
        l.add_value("price", response.meta["price"])
        l.add_value("seller", response.meta["seller"])
        l.add_value("image_urls", response.meta["image_urls"])
        l.add_value("property_url", response.url)
        return l.load_item()
```

The reason there is a parse_item function is that I plan to add a few more fields that are present in the individual property page. But before I add that I ran into this issue of "KeyError: 'prop_type'" and "KeyError: 'image_urls'" (tried commenting our prop_type related line and then found the issue with  image_urls). If I comment out the related lines for both prop_type and image_urls, no more errors pop up.

Just to check, I tried to print just the response.meta and found that prop_type is indeed present there (response beautified for easy readability).

```
{
'title': '6 bedroom terraced house for sale',
'address': 'Elm Row, Hampstead, NW3',
'prop_type': 'Terraced',
'price': 6500000,
'seller': 'Amberden Estates',
'image_urls': [
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_00_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_01_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_02_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_03_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_04_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_05_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_06_0000.JPG',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_07_0000.JPG',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_08_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_09_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_10_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_11_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_12_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_13_0000.jpg',
'https://media.rightmove.co.uk/91k/90643/78984818/90643_Ambhj77ty543_IMG_14_0000.jpg'
],
'depth': 1,
'download_timeout': 180.0,
'download_slot': 'www.rightmove.co.uk',
'download_latency': 0.5458950996398926
}
```

EDIT_1: Adding Logs

```
2020-07-16 20:11:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-93846041.html> (referer: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/api/_search?locationIdentifier=POSTCODE%5E620536&numberOfPropertiesPerPage=24&radius=1.0&sortType=2&viewType=LIST&channel=BUY&currencyCode=GBP&index=25)
2020-07-16 20:11:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-93846041.html> (referer: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/api/_search?locationIdentifier=POSTCODE%5E620536&numberOfPropertiesPerPage=24&radius=1.0&sortType=2&viewType=LIST&channel=BUY&currencyCode=GBP&index=25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jaunting_duo/PycharmProjects/python_scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/jaunting_duo/PycharmProjects/python_scrapy/properties_data/properties_data/spiders/rightmove.py", line 67, in parse_item
    l.add_value("prop_type", response.meta["prop_type"])
  File "/home/jaunting_duo/PycharmProjects/python_scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 88, in add_value
    self._add_value(field_name, value)
  File "/home/jaunting_duo/PycharmProjects/python_scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 102, in _add_value
    processed_value = self._process_input_value(field_name, value)
  File "/home/jaunting_duo/PycharmProjects/python_scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 165, in _process_input_value
    proc = self.get_input_processor(field_name)
  File "/home/jaunting_duo/PycharmProjects/python_scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 153, in get_input_processor
    proc = self._get_item_field_attr(field_name, 'input_processor',
  File "/home/jaunting_duo/PycharmProjects/python_scrapy/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 178, in _get_item_field_attr
    value = self.item.fields[field_name].get(key, default)
KeyError: 'prop_type'
```

I'm totally stuck as to why the other data points are working fine but prop_type and image_urls are causing errors. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: indeed intriguing, I can't stop the problem, can you share the logs when the error happens?

Comment: Hi @eLRuLL Thanks for the response. Updated the question with the logs.

Comment: ok, it looks like you forgot to add `prop_type` as a field in the PropertiesDataItem, please check that, should be the same with `image_urls`

Comment: Thanks. This worked. That was such a silly mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted your `items.py`, or wherever you defined your `PropertiesDataItem`, but the error in your logs are consistent with the Item not having the fields you are trying to load.

Check if your PropertiesDataItem have all the these items:

```
title
address
prop_type
price
seller
image_urls
property_url
```

Comment: This solved it! Such a rookie mistake. prop_type was initially "type" but I changed it to prop_type only in the spider and not in items.py and a simple typo with the image_urls (it was image_url in items.py). Thanks a ton!